# How to be notified by email

Tags: facebook, notifications

In the following two situations I need notifications by email:

1. Message in Facebook: I was able to get email notifications earlier, but somehow I cannot anymore. What do I need to change?
2. In my blog when people left comments through FB (like http://blog.yam.com/shamba/article/49373574 ...from "Ta Lotus"): I don't get notifications thus missing critical messages...otherwise can I turn this function (leaving comments thru FB) off?

Comment: For your second question, see [this StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9294156/198836).

Answer (score 1):

For your first question, follow the steps below:

1. Go to **Account Settings**
2. Click on **Notifications** from the left-side menu (the direct link to this page is https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=notifications&section=Facebook&view)
3. Scroll to the **All Notifications** section
   [image]
4. Click **Edit** for the Facebook category
   [image]
5. Click to check the checkbox for **Sends you a message**
   [image]
6. Click on **Save Changes** at the end of the list